# Would it be useful to invite tag wiki edit reviewers to check for possible copy-pastes?

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

I see that tag wiki edits simply copy-pasting definitions from the Internet are still being accepted while [they shouldn't](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2125/32746) and simply typing the suggested definition on any search engine shows that it is not original content.

Here is [an example among others](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79469).

Would it be useful to add some specific advice on the suggested tag edit review page, to invite reviewers to ensure that the suggested content is original and not some copy-paste?

Comment: Since these suggestions mostly come from a single user, maybe you should talk with the user. Granted, that doesn't solve the deeper problem of copy-pastes getting approved.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Thanks for the edit. If SE works as I suppose, he should have been informed of the rejects with the clear rejection motives and already received my notification linking the same thread I link here (the "they shouldn't" part) which does a good job in explaining what tag wikis are supposed to contain. Because *yes*, good content too allows to get badges ;) !

Comment: You're welcome. The user didn't interact with the linked question, so they probably didn't get a notification. I took the liberty of commenting on one of the user's own posts. Next time he/she logs in, he/she should get a notification.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks for the notification. I won't use copy-pastes on the tag wiki's anymore. I wasn't aware of it. Is it allowed to copy paste when the source is added?

Comment: @EvanderConsus Attribution often helps. But to be on the safe side, it's better to create original content. The page that WhiteWinterWolf linked (http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/please-do-not-dump-wikipedia-into-tag-wikis) should give you the info you need.

Answer (score 4):

I think that is a good idea.

I am one of the persons who accepted that particular edit. I simply did not think about googling to see if it was a copy paste. Had there been a friendly reminder in the top bar (when you click more) I would probably have done so.

Comment: I had this because a few time ago, when handling the review queue, my attention was caught by a specific banner reading something like *"The system has detected this post to be a possible spam, please review it carrefully!"*. This clearly raised my attention and I think that a similar banner could indeed help to avoid routinely validating the suggested edit due to the content being well-formed and making sense. Otherwise I think that everybody is deemed to do the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe another way to handle this is to have a script that checks google or other search engines for the text and if it gets a valid hit back rejects the proposed edit(this would sadly have to be server side to prevent people from getting around it). With this a copy pasta version could never go up. The problem is trying to handle small edits to try and bypass this filter. This probably is not feasible though due to the amount of work required to sanitize it, but it's food for though.

Comment: Cybermonkey already had proposed the idea below [Gilles' recommendations](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/2125/32746) regarding tag wiki edits. If it could be done, this would be nice, but I think it may be complex to implement and may have noticeable side-effects. On the other side, the editing advice is already up-and-running, so the modification could be minimal and with the least possible side-effects.